# Configure webAPI oData name for odata.count

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata

Anyone know how to customize the names asp.net webapi returns?  I'm really interested in changing "odata.count" to be something like "odata-count" - the dot is messing up Infragistics IgniteUI controls.

Example URL: `http://localhost/odata/users?$inlineCount=allpages&$top=10`

Example oData:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://mydomain/odata/$metadata#Users",
  "odata.count":"3",
  "value":[
    {"FirstName":"Alan","MiddleName":"A.","LastName":"Arlington"},
    {"FirstName":"Brad","MiddleName":"B.","LastName":"Boston"},
    {"FirstName":"Dirk","MiddleName":"J.","LastName":"Watkins"}
  ]
}
```

I could also live with putting all oData metadata in a separate top-level object like:

```
{
  "odata":{
    "metadata":"http://mydomain/odata/$metadata#Users",
    "count":"3",  
  },
  "value":[
    {"FirstName":"Alan","MiddleName":"A.","LastName":"Arlington"},
    {"FirstName":"Brad","MiddleName":"B.","LastName":"Boston"},
    {"FirstName":"Dirk","MiddleName":"J.","LastName":"Watkins"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData protocol [defines](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/csprd01/odata-json-format-v4.0-csprd01.html) a standard representation for OData requests and responses in JSON format. The metadata key names like odata.count are defined by the spec and are not configurable to improv inter-operability with standard clients.

In short, you cannot customize those names.